Semistable reduction of Elliptic curves
Let $E$ be an Elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $p$ be a prime at which $E$ has semistable reduction i.e. either good reduction or multiplicative reduction.
Let's see the same $E$ as an Elliptic curve over a number field $K$. Is it true that for every prime $\mathfrak{p}$ above $p$, $E$ has semistable reduction?

Yes. Good reduction remains good reduction, and multiplicative reduction remains multiplicative: all you are doing is base-extending the special fibre from $\mathbb{F}p$ to some finite extension $k{\mathfrak{p}}$, and if $E_p$ is smooth, resp. has a nodal singularity, then its base-extension is still smooth, resp. has a nodal singularity.

Can you suggest a reference for this result?

See Silverman Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, Proposition VII.5.4.
